# Python: help to make a regexp

Tags: python, regex

I'm not very experienced in regexs.

And now I think I need it for this purpose:

I want the regex to find variables like `5c` or `c5` (only one variant not both) in a string. In the future the table may grow and i'll need to find vars like `25ac` or `ac25`

The variable would always be number+letter(or two), it's kind of table cells numeration (like in Excel)

```
/[0-9]+[a-z]{1,2}/
```

something like that?
Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: corrected my question

Comment: Why are you using slashes in your regex? Python's regex syntax for finding is `re.findall('[0-9]+[a-z]{1,2}', str)`

Comment: @Jerry thx. As I said I'm not experienced in using regex

Comment: @c00p3r.web well okay, but something I think is worth noting is that the regex in the answer you accepted accepts both 5c _and_ c5, while the regex you came up with should fit what you want, of course, if you use the right functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want something like this:

```
^(\d+[a-zA-Z]{1,2})|([a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d+)$
```

To break this down, the `^` is the start of a string/line while the `$` ends the string/line. You then have a capturing group (what the regex captures in your match) which has a digit character, `\d` (so 0-9), 1 or more times (which is given by a `+`) followed by 1 to 2 (signified by the `{1,2}`) letters (the `[]` characters contain ranges of characters to match, which in our case is all of the alphabet, uppercase and lowercase) and then an or sign `|` and then the same pattern but reversed.

http://www.regex101.com/ is a pretty useful resource for playing with regexes and http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html is a great site showing you everything about regexes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest solution ...

```
(\d+\w+|\w+\d+)
```

Comment: `\w` matches digits as well so this will match `25` for example. It also matches `abc123` and the OP only wanted it to match up to 2 letter characters